# iphone + facebook, Data Store API

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm doing a game that will connect to facebook
once conected the game uploads your score and shows you a table with the score of your friends.

I try to create an object to store data, but i couldn't do it.

then I read this on the Data Store API documentation:
Except for the User Preference API methods, all Data Store API methods have been disabled for desktop applications.

Is my game an desktop application?
if not, how can i do for store the points of the players in the facebook application?

I'm so sorry for mi english, I speak spanish.

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store your game data, you have to create your own database and a webservice to connect your clients with that database. There's no way around it. But there're several helpful question on that topic on stackoverflow.

An alternative be would using online services like http://iphonelb.com/

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, the application is a "Desktop" application.